# How can I add a space between every 3 characters counting from the right to the left in a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, format

I want to add space between every 3 characters in a string in C#, but count from right to left.

For example :

```
11222333 -> 11 222 333
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the code you're trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer by @Jimi from comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72595588/how-can-i-add-a-space-between-every-3-characters-counting-from-the-right-to-the#comment128236526_72595588) (will delete if they post their own)

```cs
var YourString = "11222333";

var sb = new StringBuilder(YourString);
for (int i = sb.Length -3; i >= 0; i -= 3)
  sb.Insert(i, ' ');

return sb.ToString();
```

The benefit of this algorithm appears to be that you are working backwards through the string and therefore only moving a certain amount on each run, rather than the whole string.

Comment: The *benefits* (let's call it that) are: you don't create garbage, you can specify any position inside the string, the position can be easily configured, it's way faster than manipulating strings (when this counts). -- This format `(i, new[] { ' ' }, 0, 1)` enforces single char separator, while this other: `sb.Insert(i, " ", N)` allows to insert `N` chars in the specified positions.

Comment: It's a community wiki, feel free to edit to your heart's content (or for that matter create your own). Not clear what you mean: "`(i, new[] { ' ' }, 0, 1)` enforces single char separator" yes but so does `sb.Insert(i, ' ');` and it doesn't create a new array on each loop.

Comment: `sb.Insert(i, ' ')` doesn't allow to insert more than one char in the current position. It doesn't *enforce*, it simply cannot. While a configurable expression, in the first case, will throw if you try to add more chars that allowed (and this can be configured). In the second case, you can add as many chars as you want. -- The capacity can be defined as `[Value].Length + (N_Chars * ([Value].Length % [Position])) + 1` -- Just some notes for whomever may be interested.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to format a string as a number according to some locale conventions you can use the NumberFormat class to set how you want a number to be formatted as a string

So for example

```
string input = "11222333";
NumberFormatInfo currentFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
currentFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
if(Int32.TryParse(input, NumberStyles.None, currentFormat, out int result))
{
    string output = result.ToString("N0", currentFormat);
    Console.WriteLine(output); // 11 222 333
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following recursive function would do the job:

```
string space3(string s)
{
    int len3 = s.Length - 3;

    return (len <= 0) ? s 
          : (space3(s.Substring(0, len3)) + " " + s.Substring(len3));
}
```

[C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) introduced [string ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes). Ranges allow for a more compact form:

```
string space3(string s)
{
   return (s.Length <= 3) ? s 
             : (space3(s[..^3]) + " " + s[^3..]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions)):

```
string input = "11222333";
string result = Regex.Replace( input, @"\d{3}", @" $0", RegexOptions.RightToLeft );
```

Demo and detailed explanation of RegEx pattern at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SNlRP4/1).

**tl;dr:** Match groups of 3 digits from right to left and replace them by space + the 3 digits.

Answer (score 0):

The **most efficient** algorithm I can come up with is the following:

```
    var sb = new StringBuilder(YourString.Length + YourString.Length / 3 + 1);
    if (YourString.Length % 3 > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(YourString, 0, YourString.Length % 3);
        sb.Append(' ');
    }
    
    for (var i = YourString.Length % 3; i < YourString.Length; i += 3)
    {
        sb.Append(YourString, i, 3);
        sb.Append(' ');
    }


    return sb.ToString();
```

We first assign a `StringBuilder` of the correct size.

Then we check to see if we need to append the first one or two characters. Then we loop the rest.

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ySOpeN)